# A Deck of Cards

Tags: sorting

my roommate and I have been trying to figure this out, and I was attempting to write a program to simulate the problem to shed some light on it.

A deck of 52 cards in "new deck order" (Deck 0) is sorted into two piles by taking the top card and putting it in Pile A and taking the next 
card and putting it in Pile B and repeating until there are no more cards in the deck. Pile A is then put on top of Pile B, forming Deck 1.
After eight different iterations of the sorting algorithm, creating Deck 8, the cards are in new deck order again. Why does it take 8 iterations of
this particular sorting algorithm to return the deck of cards to new deck order?

Comment: Persi Diaconis studied this back in about 1975, I believe. You might look for "Diaconis shuffling" and see if it leads you to his papers, which would almost certainly answer this question.

Comment: Your shuffle is a permutation of the list 1, 2, ..., 52. You can write any such permutation as a product of disjoint cycles, and from that it's easy to work out how many times you have to iterate it to get back to where you started.

Comment: Gerry's right...and in a way, that gets to what I was going to say before I pointed to Diaconis: it takes 8 iterations because...it takes 8 iterations. If your shuffle just took one card from the bottom and placed it on top, it'd take 52 iterations. Why? Because it does. But take a look at Diaconis anyhow...you'll probably find it interesting.

Comment: Thank you two! The paper "Trailing the Dovetail Shuffle to Its Lair" has been a fascinating read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth - I modeled it on a spreadsheet - the way I interpreted it Deck 27 is Deck 1 in reverse order and Deck 53 is the first repeat of Deck 1.

So, unless I am misinterpreting how you are shuffling, it will actually take 52 iterations to return to a full deck.

[image: Deck Shuffling]